# Shouldn't I be able to flag while suspended on chat?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, chat, account-suspension

I was (for some reason or another) suspended in the [tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

I am trying to flag a random message for a moderator, but the system is not letting me because it thinks it is a "vote" and I get this message:

[image]

What is going on here?

<sub><sub><sub><sub>And if someone can, can you remove my suspension? :-)</sub></sub></sub></sub>

---

<sub>Side point: [The message](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/1712467/history) I was suspended for was [**asked for** by the other user](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1712457#1712457). It was a joke :-)</sub>

Comment: Why are you suspended???

Comment: I added it as a side point to my post @JanDvorak I have no idea

Comment: your link is 404

Comment: It's likely an automatic 30-minute suspension because people flagged something you said. My prediction is this will be treated as "by design" and you'll be told to vote/flag when your suspension is over.

Comment: @Pëkka that is possible, but still quite odd...

Comment: Are you sure you have enough `<sub>`'s there :)

Comment: No. I definitely need more @StuartC :-D

Comment: Upvoting not because I agree (that suspended users should be flagged) but I think the question (and answer) are useful.

Comment: Thanks @JDB Still not sure why it was downvoted in general, but whatever. I shall survive :-)

Comment: @qwertynl I'm not a downvoter, but the issue I see that is probably contributing is the presence of the [bug] tag and the phrasing of the question.  Given how the question is phrased, it appears as if you are claiming that the bug is the fact that you can't flag posts while suspended in chat.  Similar, the edited title also gives the appearance that you are proposing a feature to let you flag while suspended in chat, so users *could* be voting in agreement/disagreement.  If your [bug] is the message referencing voting, then make the question about that.

Answer (score 16):

Suspension is the only option moderators have available to stop someone from abusing flags. So they should certainly stop a user from flagging, else there would be no defense at all against abusive flagging.

Suspension stops you from doing *anything*, because pretty much ever action you can perform could be abused.

Comment: What does this have to do with abusive flagging?

Comment: @qwertynl This is why you can't flag while banned, which is what (at least your title) asked